# Silviomoreto Bootstrap-selectpicker data-live-search attribute enquiry

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-select

I want to ask about the Silviomoreto Bootstrap-selectpicker data-live-search attribute function.

Currently, the search result will return all the results containing the characters I entered. I want to changes it to returned the results based on first few characters that I entered.

For example:-

CURRENTLY
I search for "ma", then the result will return Bahamas, Cayman Island, Christmas Island.... [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKBXx.png)

PREFERABLE
I search for "ma", then the result will return Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia.... [view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCBi.png)

Here I attached with the sample code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
     $(".selectpicker.").selectpicker();
});
</script>
<div class="container">
<select class="form-control selectpicker input-sm " data-live-search="true" id="country" name="country">
   selected
   <option value="AF" selected>Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="AL" >Albania</option>
   <option value="DZ" >Algeria</option>
   <option value="AS" >American Samoa</option>
   <option value="AD" >Andorra</option>
   <option value="AO" >Angola</option>
   <option value="AI" >Anguilla</option>
   <option value="AQ" >Antarctica</option>
   <option value="AG" >Antigua and Barbuda</option>
   <option value="AR" >Argentina</option>
   <option value="AM" >Armenia</option>
   <option value="AW" >Aruba</option>
   <option value="AU" >Australia</option>
   <option value="AT" >Austria</option>
   <option value="AZ" >Azerbaijan</option>
   <option value="BS" >Bahamas</option>
   <option value="BH" >Bahrain</option>
   <option value="BD" >Bangladesh</option>
   <option value="BB" >Barbados</option>
   <option value="BY" >Belarus</option>
   <option value="BE" >Belgium</option>
   <option value="BZ" >Belize</option>
   <option value="BJ" >Benin</option>
   <option value="BM" >Bermuda</option>
   <option value="BT" >Bhutan</option>
   <option value="BO" >Bolivia (Plurinational State of)</option>
   <option value="BA" >Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
   <option value="BW" >Botswana</option>
   <option value="BV" >Bouvet Island</option>
   <option value="BR" >Brazil</option>
   <option value="IO" >British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
   <option value="VG" >British Virgin Islands</option>
   <option value="BN" >Brunei Darussalam</option>
   <option value="BG" >Bulgaria</option>
   <option value="BF" >Burkina Faso</option>
   <option value="BI" >Burundi</option>
   <option value="KH" >Cambodia</option>
   <option value="CM" >Cameroon</option>
   <option value="CA" >Canada</option>
   <option value="CV" >Cabo Verde</option>
   <option value="BQ" >Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
   <option value="KY" >Cayman Islands</option>
   <option value="CF" >Central African Republic</option>
   <option value="TD" >Chad</option>
   <option value="CL" >Chile</option>
   <option value="CN" >China</option>
   <option value="CX" >Christmas Island</option>
   <option value="CC" >Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
   <option value="CO" >Colombia</option>
   <option value="KM" >Comoros</option>
   <option value="CG" >Congo</option>
   <option value="CD" >Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
   <option value="CK" >Cook Islands</option>
   <option value="CR" >Costa Rica</option>
   <option value="HR" >Croatia</option>
   <option value="CU" >Cuba</option>
   <option value="CW" >Cura</option>
   <option value="CY" >Cyprus</option>
   <option value="CZ" >Czechia</option>
   <option value="CI" >Côte d'Ivoire</option>
   <option value="DK" >Denmark</option>
   <option value="DJ" >Djibouti</option>
   <option value="DM" >Dominica</option>
   <option value="DO" >Dominican Republic</option>
   <option value="EC" >Ecuador</option>
   <option value="EG" >Egypt</option>
   <option value="SV" >El Salvador</option>
   <option value="GQ" >Equatorial Guinea</option>
   <option value="ER" >Eritrea</option>
   <option value="EE" >Estonia</option>
   <option value="ET" >Ethiopia</option>
   <option value="FK" >Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
   <option value="FO" >Faeroe Islands</option>
   <option value="FJ" >Fiji</option>
   <option value="FI" >Finland</option>
   <option value="FR" >France</option>
   <option value="GF" >French Guiana</option>
   <option value="PF" >French Polynesia</option>
   <option value="TF" >French Southern Territories</option>
   <option value="GA" >Gabon</option>
   <option value="GM" >Gambia</option>
   <option value="GE" >Georgia</option>
   <option value="DE" >Germany</option>
   <option value="GH" >Ghana</option>
   <option value="GI" >Gibraltar</option>
   <option value="GR" >Greece</option>
   <option value="GL" >Greenland</option>
   <option value="GD" >Grenada</option>
   <option value="GP" >Guadeloupe</option>
   <option value="GU" >Guam</option>
   <option value="GT" >Guatemala</option>
   <option value="GG" >Guernsey</option>
   <option value="GN" >Guinea</option>
   <option value="GW" >Guinea-Bissau</option>
   <option value="GY" >Guyana</option>
   <option value="HT" >Haiti</option>
   <option value="HM" >Heard & McDonald Islands</option>
   <option value="HN" >Honduras</option>
   <option value="HK" >Hong Kong</option>
   <option value="HU" >Hungary</option>
   <option value="IS" >Iceland</option>
   <option value="IN" >India</option>
   <option value="ID" >Indonesia</option>
   <option value="IR" >Iran (Islamic Republic of)</option>
   <option value="IQ" >Iraq</option>
   <option value="IE" >Ireland</option>
   <option value="IM" >Isle of Man</option>
   <option value="IL" >Israel</option>
   <option value="IT" >Italy</option>
   <option value="JM" >Jamaica</option>
   <option value="JP" >Japan</option>
   <option value="JE" >Jersey</option>
   <option value="JO" >Jordan</option>
   <option value="KZ" >Kazakhstan</option>
   <option value="KE" >Kenya</option>
   <option value="KI" >Kiribati</option>
   <option value="KW" >Kuwait</option>
   <option value="KG" >Kyrgyzstan</option>
   <option value="LA" >Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
   <option value="LV" >Latvia</option>
   <option value="LB" >Lebanon</option>
   <option value="LS" >Lesotho</option>
   <option value="LR" >Liberia</option>
   <option value="LY" >Libya</option>
   <option value="LI" >Liechtenstein</option>
   <option value="LT" >Lithuania</option>
   <option value="LU" >Luxembourg</option>
   <option value="MO" >China, Macao Special Administrative Region</option>
   <option value="MK" >The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</option>
   <option value="MG" >Madagascar</option>
   <option value="MW" >Malawi</option>
   <option value="MY" >Malaysia</option>
   <option value="MV" >Maldives</option>
   <option value="ML" >Mali</option>
   <option value="MT" >Malta</option>
   <option value="MH" >Marshall Islands</option>
   <option value="MQ" >Martinique</option>
   <option value="MR" >Mauritania</option>
   <option value="MU" >Mauritius</option>
   <option value="YT" >Mayotte</option>
   <option value="MX" >Mexico</option>
   <option value="FM" >Micronesia (Federated States of)</option>
   <option value="MD" >Republic of Moldova</option>
   <option value="MC" >Monaco</option>
   <option value="MN" >Mongolia</option>
   <option value="ME" >Montenegro</option>
   <option value="MS" >Montserrat</option>
   <option value="MA" >Morocco</option>
   <option value="MZ" >Mozambique</option>
   <option value="MM" >Myanmar</option>
   <option value="NA" >Namibia</option>
   <option value="NR" >Nauru</option>
   <option value="NP" >Nepal</option>
   <option value="NL" >Netherlands</option>
   <option value="NC" >New Caledonia</option>
   <option value="NZ" >New Zealand</option>
   <option value="NI" >Nicaragua</option>
   <option value="NE" >Niger</option>
   <option value="NG" >Nigeria</option>
   <option value="NU" >Niue</option>
   <option value="NF" >Norfolk Island</option>
   <option value="KP" >North Korea</option>
   <option value="MP" >Northern Mariana Islands</option>
   <option value="NO" >Norway</option>
   <option value="OM" >Oman</option>
   <option value="PK" >Pakistan</option>
   <option value="PW" >Palau</option>
   <option value="PS" >State of Palestine</option>
   <option value="PA" >Panama</option>
   <option value="PG" >Papua New Guinea</option>
   <option value="PY" >Paraguay</option>
   <option value="PE" >Peru</option>
   <option value="PH" >Philippines</option>
   <option value="PN" >Pitcairn</option>
   <option value="PL" >Poland</option>
   <option value="PT" >Portugal</option>
   <option value="PR" >Puerto Rico</option>
   <option value="QA" >Qatar</option>
   <option value="RO" >Romania</option>
   <option value="RU" >Russian Federation</option>
   <option value="RW" >Rwanda</option>
   <option value="RE" >Reunion</option>
   <option value="WS" >Samoa</option>
   <option value="SM" >San Marino</option>
   <option value="SA" >Saudi Arabia</option>
   <option value="SN" >Senegal</option>
   <option value="RS" >Serbia</option>
   <option value="SC" >Seychelles</option>
   <option value="SL" >Sierra Leone</option>
   <option value="SG" >Singapore</option>
   <option value="SX" >Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
   <option value="SK" >Slovakia</option>
   <option value="SI" >Slovenia</option>
   <option value="SB" >Solomon Islands</option>
   <option value="SO" >Somalia</option>
   <option value="ZA" >South Africa</option>
   <option value="GS" >South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands</option>
   <option value="KR" >South Korea</option>
   <option value="SS" >South Sudan</option>
   <option value="ES" >Spain</option>
   <option value="LK" >Sri Lanka</option>
   <option value="BL" >St. Barth</option>
   <option value="SH" >Saint Helena</option>
   <option value="KN" >Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
   <option value="LC" >Saint Lucia</option>
   <option value="MF" >Saint Martin (French part)</option>
   <option value="PM" >Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
   <option value="VC" >Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
   <option value="SD" >Sudan</option>
   <option value="SR" >Suriname</option>
   <option value="SJ" >Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
   <option value="SZ" >Swaziland</option>
   <option value="SE" >Sweden</option>
   <option value="CH" >Switzerland</option>
   <option value="SY" >Syrian Arab Republic</option>
   <option value="ST" >Sao Tome and Principe</option>
   <option value="TW" >Taiwan</option>
   <option value="TJ" >Tajikistan</option>
   <option value="TZ" >United Republic of Tanzania</option>
   <option value="TH" >Thailand</option>
   <option value="TL" >Timor-Leste</option>
   <option value="TG" >Togo</option>
   <option value="TK" >Tokelau</option>
   <option value="TO" >Tonga</option>
   <option value="TT" >Trinidad and Tobago</option>
   <option value="TN" >Tunisia</option>
   <option value="TR" >Turkey</option>
   <option value="TM" >Turkmenistan</option>
   <option value="TC" >Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
   <option value="TV" >Tuvalu</option>
   <option value="UM" >United States Outlying Islands</option>
   <option value="VI" >United States Virgin Islands</option>
   <option value="GB" >Ireland</option>
   <option value="US" >United States of America</option>
   <option value="UG" >Uganda</option>
   <option value="UA" >Ukraine</option>
   <option value="AE" >United Arab Emirates</option>
   <option value="UY" >Uruguay</option>
   <option value="UZ" >Uzbekistan</option>
   <option value="VU" >Vanuatu</option>
   <option value="VA" >Holy See</option>
   <option value="VE" >Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)</option>
   <option value="VN" >Viet Nam</option>
   <option value="WF" >Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
   <option value="EH" >Western Sahara</option>
   <option value="YE" >Yemen</option>
   <option value="ZM" >Zambia</option>
   <option value="ZW" >Zimbabwe</option>
   <option value="AX" >A land Islands</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add *data-live-search-style="startsWith"* to your select :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
     $(".selectpicker.").selectpicker();
});
</script>
<div class="container">
<select class="form-control selectpicker input-sm " data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" id="country" name="country">
   selected
   <option value="AF" selected>Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="AL" >Albania</option>
   <option value="DZ" >Algeria</option>
   <option value="AS" >American Samoa</option>
   <option value="AD" >Andorra</option>
   <option value="AO" >Angola</option>
   <option value="AI" >Anguilla</option>
   <option value="AQ" >Antarctica</option>
   <option value="AG" >Antigua and Barbuda</option>
   <option value="AR" >Argentina</option>
   <option value="AM" >Armenia</option>
   <option value="AW" >Aruba</option>
   <option value="AU" >Australia</option>
   <option value="AT" >Austria</option>
   <option value="AZ" >Azerbaijan</option>
   <option value="BS" >Bahamas</option>
   <option value="BH" >Bahrain</option>
   <option value="BD" >Bangladesh</option>
   <option value="BB" >Barbados</option>
   <option value="BY" >Belarus</option>
   <option value="BE" >Belgium</option>
   <option value="BZ" >Belize</option>
   <option value="BJ" >Benin</option>
   <option value="BM" >Bermuda</option>
   <option value="BT" >Bhutan</option>
   <option value="BO" >Bolivia (Plurinational State of)</option>
   <option value="BA" >Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
   <option value="BW" >Botswana</option>
   <option value="BV" >Bouvet Island</option>
   <option value="BR" >Brazil</option>
   <option value="IO" >British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
   <option value="VG" >British Virgin Islands</option>
   <option value="BN" >Brunei Darussalam</option>
   <option value="BG" >Bulgaria</option>
   <option value="BF" >Burkina Faso</option>
   <option value="BI" >Burundi</option>
   <option value="KH" >Cambodia</option>
   <option value="CM" >Cameroon</option>
   <option value="CA" >Canada</option>
   <option value="CV" >Cabo Verde</option>
   <option value="BQ" >Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
   <option value="KY" >Cayman Islands</option>
   <option value="CF" >Central African Republic</option>
   <option value="TD" >Chad</option>
   <option value="CL" >Chile</option>
   <option value="CN" >China</option>
   <option value="CX" >Christmas Island</option>
   <option value="CC" >Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
   <option value="CO" >Colombia</option>
   <option value="KM" >Comoros</option>
   <option value="CG" >Congo</option>
   <option value="CD" >Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
   <option value="CK" >Cook Islands</option>
   <option value="CR" >Costa Rica</option>
   <option value="HR" >Croatia</option>
   <option value="CU" >Cuba</option>
   <option value="CW" >Cura</option>
   <option value="CY" >Cyprus</option>
   <option value="CZ" >Czechia</option>
   <option value="CI" >Côte d'Ivoire</option>
   <option value="DK" >Denmark</option>
   <option value="DJ" >Djibouti</option>
   <option value="DM" >Dominica</option>
   <option value="DO" >Dominican Republic</option>
   <option value="EC" >Ecuador</option>
   <option value="EG" >Egypt</option>
   <option value="SV" >El Salvador</option>
   <option value="GQ" >Equatorial Guinea</option>
   <option value="ER" >Eritrea</option>
   <option value="EE" >Estonia</option>
   <option value="ET" >Ethiopia</option>
   <option value="FK" >Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
   <option value="FO" >Faeroe Islands</option>
   <option value="FJ" >Fiji</option>
   <option value="FI" >Finland</option>
   <option value="FR" >France</option>
   <option value="GF" >French Guiana</option>
   <option value="PF" >French Polynesia</option>
   <option value="TF" >French Southern Territories</option>
   <option value="GA" >Gabon</option>
   <option value="GM" >Gambia</option>
   <option value="GE" >Georgia</option>
   <option value="DE" >Germany</option>
   <option value="GH" >Ghana</option>
   <option value="GI" >Gibraltar</option>
   <option value="GR" >Greece</option>
   <option value="GL" >Greenland</option>
   <option value="GD" >Grenada</option>
   <option value="GP" >Guadeloupe</option>
   <option value="GU" >Guam</option>
   <option value="GT" >Guatemala</option>
   <option value="GG" >Guernsey</option>
   <option value="GN" >Guinea</option>
   <option value="GW" >Guinea-Bissau</option>
   <option value="GY" >Guyana</option>
   <option value="HT" >Haiti</option>
   <option value="HM" >Heard & McDonald Islands</option>
   <option value="HN" >Honduras</option>
   <option value="HK" >Hong Kong</option>
   <option value="HU" >Hungary</option>
   <option value="IS" >Iceland</option>
   <option value="IN" >India</option>
   <option value="ID" >Indonesia</option>
   <option value="IR" >Iran (Islamic Republic of)</option>
   <option value="IQ" >Iraq</option>
   <option value="IE" >Ireland</option>
   <option value="IM" >Isle of Man</option>
   <option value="IL" >Israel</option>
   <option value="IT" >Italy</option>
   <option value="JM" >Jamaica</option>
   <option value="JP" >Japan</option>
   <option value="JE" >Jersey</option>
   <option value="JO" >Jordan</option>
   <option value="KZ" >Kazakhstan</option>
   <option value="KE" >Kenya</option>
   <option value="KI" >Kiribati</option>
   <option value="KW" >Kuwait</option>
   <option value="KG" >Kyrgyzstan</option>
   <option value="LA" >Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
   <option value="LV" >Latvia</option>
   <option value="LB" >Lebanon</option>
   <option value="LS" >Lesotho</option>
   <option value="LR" >Liberia</option>
   <option value="LY" >Libya</option>
   <option value="LI" >Liechtenstein</option>
   <option value="LT" >Lithuania</option>
   <option value="LU" >Luxembourg</option>
   <option value="MO" >China, Macao Special Administrative Region</option>
   <option value="MK" >The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</option>
   <option value="MG" >Madagascar</option>
   <option value="MW" >Malawi</option>
   <option value="MY" >Malaysia</option>
   <option value="MV" >Maldives</option>
   <option value="ML" >Mali</option>
   <option value="MT" >Malta</option>
   <option value="MH" >Marshall Islands</option>
   <option value="MQ" >Martinique</option>
   <option value="MR" >Mauritania</option>
   <option value="MU" >Mauritius</option>
   <option value="YT" >Mayotte</option>
   <option value="MX" >Mexico</option>
   <option value="FM" >Micronesia (Federated States of)</option>
   <option value="MD" >Republic of Moldova</option>
   <option value="MC" >Monaco</option>
   <option value="MN" >Mongolia</option>
   <option value="ME" >Montenegro</option>
   <option value="MS" >Montserrat</option>
   <option value="MA" >Morocco</option>
   <option value="MZ" >Mozambique</option>
   <option value="MM" >Myanmar</option>
   <option value="NA" >Namibia</option>
   <option value="NR" >Nauru</option>
   <option value="NP" >Nepal</option>
   <option value="NL" >Netherlands</option>
   <option value="NC" >New Caledonia</option>
   <option value="NZ" >New Zealand</option>
   <option value="NI" >Nicaragua</option>
   <option value="NE" >Niger</option>
   <option value="NG" >Nigeria</option>
   <option value="NU" >Niue</option>
   <option value="NF" >Norfolk Island</option>
   <option value="KP" >North Korea</option>
   <option value="MP" >Northern Mariana Islands</option>
   <option value="NO" >Norway</option>
   <option value="OM" >Oman</option>
   <option value="PK" >Pakistan</option>
   <option value="PW" >Palau</option>
   <option value="PS" >State of Palestine</option>
   <option value="PA" >Panama</option>
   <option value="PG" >Papua New Guinea</option>
   <option value="PY" >Paraguay</option>
   <option value="PE" >Peru</option>
   <option value="PH" >Philippines</option>
   <option value="PN" >Pitcairn</option>
   <option value="PL" >Poland</option>
   <option value="PT" >Portugal</option>
   <option value="PR" >Puerto Rico</option>
   <option value="QA" >Qatar</option>
   <option value="RO" >Romania</option>
   <option value="RU" >Russian Federation</option>
   <option value="RW" >Rwanda</option>
   <option value="RE" >Reunion</option>
   <option value="WS" >Samoa</option>
   <option value="SM" >San Marino</option>
   <option value="SA" >Saudi Arabia</option>
   <option value="SN" >Senegal</option>
   <option value="RS" >Serbia</option>
   <option value="SC" >Seychelles</option>
   <option value="SL" >Sierra Leone</option>
   <option value="SG" >Singapore</option>
   <option value="SX" >Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
   <option value="SK" >Slovakia</option>
   <option value="SI" >Slovenia</option>
   <option value="SB" >Solomon Islands</option>
   <option value="SO" >Somalia</option>
   <option value="ZA" >South Africa</option>
   <option value="GS" >South Georgia & South Sandwich Islands</option>
   <option value="KR" >South Korea</option>
   <option value="SS" >South Sudan</option>
   <option value="ES" >Spain</option>
   <option value="LK" >Sri Lanka</option>
   <option value="BL" >St. Barth</option>
   <option value="SH" >Saint Helena</option>
   <option value="KN" >Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
   <option value="LC" >Saint Lucia</option>
   <option value="MF" >Saint Martin (French part)</option>
   <option value="PM" >Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
   <option value="VC" >Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
   <option value="SD" >Sudan</option>
   <option value="SR" >Suriname</option>
   <option value="SJ" >Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
   <option value="SZ" >Swaziland</option>
   <option value="SE" >Sweden</option>
   <option value="CH" >Switzerland</option>
   <option value="SY" >Syrian Arab Republic</option>
   <option value="ST" >Sao Tome and Principe</option>
   <option value="TW" >Taiwan</option>
   <option value="TJ" >Tajikistan</option>
   <option value="TZ" >United Republic of Tanzania</option>
   <option value="TH" >Thailand</option>
   <option value="TL" >Timor-Leste</option>
   <option value="TG" >Togo</option>
   <option value="TK" >Tokelau</option>
   <option value="TO" >Tonga</option>
   <option value="TT" >Trinidad and Tobago</option>
   <option value="TN" >Tunisia</option>
   <option value="TR" >Turkey</option>
   <option value="TM" >Turkmenistan</option>
   <option value="TC" >Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
   <option value="TV" >Tuvalu</option>
   <option value="UM" >United States Outlying Islands</option>
   <option value="VI" >United States Virgin Islands</option>
   <option value="GB" >Ireland</option>
   <option value="US" >United States of America</option>
   <option value="UG" >Uganda</option>
   <option value="UA" >Ukraine</option>
   <option value="AE" >United Arab Emirates</option>
   <option value="UY" >Uruguay</option>
   <option value="UZ" >Uzbekistan</option>
   <option value="VU" >Vanuatu</option>
   <option value="VA" >Holy See</option>
   <option value="VE" >Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)</option>
   <option value="VN" >Viet Nam</option>
   <option value="WF" >Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
   <option value="EH" >Western Sahara</option>
   <option value="YE" >Yemen</option>
   <option value="ZM" >Zambia</option>
   <option value="ZW" >Zimbabwe</option>
   <option value="AX" >A land Islands</option>
</select>
</div>
```